# How to Pause a Storyboard on MouseEnter and Resume on MouseExit

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a scrolling news ticker that is animated via a Storyboard.  It currently works pretty well but I would like to pause it whenever the Mouse is over the TextBlock and then have it resume once the mouse is moved off of the TextBlock

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="Ticker" >
<TextBlock Text="{Binding NewsTicker, IsAsync=True}" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"  > 
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <TextBlock.Triggers> 
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="NewsTicker">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="{Binding ElementName=Ticker, Path=ActualWidth}" To="{Binding ElementName=Ticker, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource NegConverter}}" Storyboard.TargetName="translate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:35" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewsTicker" />
                            </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewsTicker" />
                            </EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </TextBlock.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

I've tried several combinations of Pause and Resume Storyboard as well as different RoutedEvents.  I even removed the EventTrigger.ExitAction just to see if the pause would work but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `EnterActions`/`ExitActions` use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events

```
<TextBlock.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard x:Name="NewsTicker">
         <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimation ... />
         </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
      <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewsTicker" />
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
      <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewsTicker" />
   </EventTrigger>
</TextBlock.Triggers>
```

since events don't have state there is no enter/exit action there is just action when event occurs

[`EventTrigger` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Trigger objects have the Setters, EnterActions, and ExitActions properties that apply changes or actions based on the state of certain properties, while **EventTrigger objects start a set of Actions when a specified routed event occurs**

Comment: Thanks!  I was just about to say I'm going to have to look into EnterActions and ExitActions so I understand when I should and shouldn't be using them.

Comment: This worked great btw, but I realized once it started working that the TextBlock itself is moving in the WrapPanel.  Which means I would need to Pause the animation for the TextBlock when the MouseEvents fired on the WrapPanel.  When I moved them and applied the SourceName however I see the following message in my output 

"Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control"

Comment: Did you try moving all 3 triggers into `WrapPanel`?

Comment: Yea, the scrolling still works but it still only stops when your over the actual text.  Tried changing the RoutedEvents to WrapPanel.MouseEnter as well without much luck.

Comment: set background of `WrapPanel` to `Tansparent` like `<WrapPanel Background="Transparent" ...>`. Without that empty area of `WrapPanel` is not hit test visible and will trigger only on objects witin `WrapPanel`

Comment: That was an awesome little tidbit of knowledge!  I knew you had to set properties before if you were going to manipulate them in triggers etc but I didn't realize that it also applied in this kind of scenario.  Thanks a lot!  That would have stumped me for a while.